# django Test sin crear base de datos

Tags: django

Mi tests.py

```
from django.core import mail
from django.test import SimpleTestCase


class EmailTest(SimpleTestCase):

    def test_send_email(self):
        mail.send_mail(
            'Test - Subject 1', 'Test de email, primer envio',
            'notreply6@gmail.com', ['jorge.cadena@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False
           )
        self.assertEquals(len(mail.outbox), 1)
        self.assertEquals(mail.outbox[0].subject, 'Test - Subject 2')
```

quiero ejecutar el test sin crear ninguna base de datos, es posible?

Answer (score 0):

Hola para usar Django sin crear o conectarse a ninguna base de datos, lo que implicaria no usar Modelos que es el corazon de Django, en el proyecto en **settings.py** limpia el contenido de DATABASE.

```
DATABASES = {}
```

En opinion usar Django sin base de datos no tiene sentido, si solo quieres mostrar vistas estaticas y aprobechar la sintaxis de Django Template recomendaria [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) + [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/).

Saludos